# $scope.watch doesn't wait until variable is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in my controller:

```
$scope.$watch(userService.getUser, function(getUser){
          console.log(getUser);
          var user = getUser;
```

And this in my service:

```
.service('userService', function ($http, $q, auth, userFactory) {
        var user;

        userFactory.getUser2(auth.currentUser()).getValue(function(result){
            //console.log(result);
            user = result;
        });

        this.getUser = function() {
            //console.log(user);
            return user;
        }

    })
```

The code works but I get errors because my controller code is executed before the user variable is changed. I should probably work with promises, I tried this but didn't work exactly.

This is my API call in userFactory:

```
userFactory.getUser2 = function(usr){
      return{
        getValue: function(callback){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/user',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            //'authentication': 'bearer' + $window.localStorage.getItem('eva-token')
            },
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {username: usr}
          }).success(function (result) {
            //console.log("userfactory getUser:", result[0]);
            callback(result[0]);
          });
        }
      }
    };
```

Is this possible with only $scope.watch? Or should I use a promise, if so, what is the proper way to implement a promise in this situation? I tried it with $q and such but that just gives a whole other range of errors.

Comment: Everything works now, still got 2 requests however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009157/different-source-from-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either need to add a guard (an `if`) that prevents execution of the rest of the controller code before your async call has finished, or simply put the rest of the controller code inside the `$scope.$watch` callback:

```
$scope.$watch(userService.getUser, function(getUser){
  var user = getUser;

  // do the rest of your stuff
});
```

or something like this:

```
$scope.user = null;

$scope.$watch(userService.getUser, function(getUser) {
  $scope.user = getUser;
});

if($scope.user) {
  // do the rest of your stuff
}
```

In that second example, `$scope.user` (or something attached to the `$scope`) needs to be used so that it will trigger the digest cycle and reevaluate your `if` guard.

Comment: This works, waiting on some other responses which may be better practice before I mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I normally handle this situation.

First, I only have a factory that handles the $http request. I return $http, which has promise built into it. This way you avoid adding any watches and any async problems.

So my factory would look something like this:

```
userFactory = function($http){
    return{
        getUser: function(usr){
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/user',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                transformRequest: function(obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for(var p in obj)
                        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                },
                data : {username: usr}
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And in your controller you would do this:

```
userFactory.getUser('bob').success(function(response){
    $scope.user = response;
});
```

Here is how you would save the user data in a var. Every time you call getUser it will check if that var is null or not, if it's null it makes the request, and if it's not it returns that var.

```
userFactory = function($http, $q){
    var user = null;

    return{
        getUser: function(usr){
            return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                if(user) resolve(user);

                else{
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/user',
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        transformRequest: function(obj) {
                            var str = [];
                            for(var p in obj)
                                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                            return str.join("&");
                        },
                        data : {username: usr}
                    })
                    .then(function(response){
                        user = response;
                        resolve(user);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I would question if you need to use a service. I think what you're trying to do with the service is cache the User data so you're not making a lot of $http requests. If that's the case you can build that into your factory. Look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958046/preventing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-is-there-a-better-way

Comment: I'm indeed trying to keep my http requests low. What is the correct syntax to pass my options to httponce?

Comment: I edited my code to show you how I usually do it. I haven't used httponce yet, but this will work for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It still makes the same amount of requests.

Comment: Gonna give +1 for the httpOnce though, its usefull for my GET calls

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$watch` is you are listening to value change in model especially. If you are providing the function, it should return a value that will react upon `$digest` cycle, not a function that execute an Ajax request or `$http` function.

From your example, you should watch a returned value assigned to model under scope and using `$digest` function to process all the watchers or `$apply` if you were calling it from directives.