# Different source from requests?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have a service:

```
angular.module('services', [

])
    .service('userService', function ($http, $q, auth, userFactory) {
        var user = null;

        if(!user){

            userFactory.getUser2(auth.currentUser()).getValue(function(result){
                //console.log(result);
                user = result;
                console.log("request");
            });
        }

        this.getUser = function() {
            //console.log(user);
            return user;
        }

    })
;
```

This service calls a factory function:

```
userFactory.getUser2 = function(usr){
      return{
        getValue: function(callback){
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/user',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            //'authentication': 'bearer' + $window.localStorage.getItem('eva-token')
            },
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {username: usr}
          }).success(function (result) {
            //console.log("userfactory getUser:", result[0]);
            callback(result[0]);
          });
        }
      }
    };
```

Now when I execute the code, I see this in my developer tools:

[image: Network developer tools]

Where does this come from? The

> console.log("request");

Gets only executed one time, but apparently there are 2 requests?

Answer (score 0):

In short, index is the page you're on.
 
If you open a page page without specifying an index.html page then the server will try to load an index document for that folder. When Chrome needs to inform you of an `error` or `console.log()`, it can not since it does not know the actual file name.
Hence (index)